# JHipster - Using ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jhipster, jdl

for a JHipster beginner, the intro to ElasticSearch at http://www.jhipster.tech/using-elasticsearch/ is quite short.

It says:
"When the entity sub-generator is used, the generated entity gets automatically indexed by Elasticsearch, and is used in the REST endpoint."

Question:
What if JDL files are used for the entities, and jhipster jdl-import ? Will the entities also be automatically indexed, if not, how to proceed?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jdl-import uses the entity sub generator, so it's the same.